# Example search name by a specific number

Tags: string, android-studio

Example

I would like to compare the SDK number with a value and display the name of the value example sdk 25 = nougat

String sdks = Build.VERSION.SDK;

```
    int Alpha = 1;
    int Beta = 2;
    int CupCake = 3;
    int Donut = 4;
    int Eclair= 5-7;
    int Froyo = 8;
    int GingerBread = 9-10;
    int HoneyComb = 11-13;
    int IceCreamSandwich = 14-15;
    int JellyBean = 16-18;
    int KitKat = 19-20;
    int Lollipop = 21-22;
    int MarshMellow = 23;
    int Nougat = 24-25;
    int Oreo = 26-27;
    int Pie = 28;

resultview.setText(sdks);
```

Comment: Looks like you need a HashMap https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap

Comment: another way that would be useful also if you gave me an example of how to get the sdk ex number (25) and instead of. display the 25 display the (nougat)

Answer (score 0):

I think a Map solution would be simple to implement given its a small range

```
  public static void main(String []args){
        Map<Integer,String> sdkMap = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
        //populate other fields similarly
        HelloWorld.populateRange("24-25","Nougat",sdkMap);
        System.out.println(sdkMap.get(24));


     }

     public static void populateRange(String range,String name, Map<Integer,String> sdkMap){
         String[] splitNumbers = range.split("-");
         int low = Integer.parseInt(splitNumbers[0]);
         int high = Integer.parseInt(splitNumbers[1]);
         for(int i=low;i<=high;i++){
             sdkMap.put(i,name);
         }
     }
```

[Working example](http://%20http://tpcg.io/zzFOhJ)